# Can we undo the libvirt -> virtualization tag synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Currently, [libvirt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libvirt) is a synonym of [virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualization), and is mentioned in some ~800 questions (plus its client tool `virsh` is mentioned in some ~200 questions that don't mention libvirt). The synonym has caused ~200 renames, so there are people trying to use it, but are unable to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, we shouldn't synonymise *specific* tech to generic terms unless they are they only way of doing that. I don't believe that was the case even back in 2012 when this was first done.

Fixed the synonym. There are still libvirt posts using [virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualization).